# passing attributes from jsp to servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets

I am writing this very simple few lines to pass attributes from `JSP` to `servlet`. I am confused why it isn't working, while I do not see any reason for it not working. 
Here what my link looks like

`www.example.com/costvote?token=22323232323232`

my.jsp

```
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="<%= request.getParameter("token") %>" />

<% 
String token =  request.getParameter("token");

request.setAttribute("token", token);
%>
</div>

    <%  
        List<candidate> candlist = (List<candidate>) request.getAttribute("candidatelist");

        for(candidate div: candlist) { 
        %>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2"><h4><%= div.getFirstname() %></h4></div>
            <div class="col-md-2"><h4><%= div.getSurname() %></h4></div>
            <div class="col-md-2"><h4><%= div.getFaculty() %></h4></div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                    <a href="/assignvote?cand_id=<%= div.getId() %>" class="btn btn-primary">Vote</a>

                </div>
            </div>          
        </div>
            <% } %>

</div>
```

Servlet.java

```
String idOfCandidate = (String) request.getParameter("cand_id");
String Votertoken = (String) request.getAttribute("token");

log.info(Votertoken + " "+ idOfCandidate );
```

the output I am getting is:

```
Null 323424234234
```

Everything is right but it still seems not to be working.

Answer (score 0):

you should use request.getParameter() to extract request parameters

```
String idOfCandidate = (String) request.getParameter("cand_id");
String Votertoken = (String) request.getParameter("token");

log.info(Votertoken + " "+ idOfCandidate );
```

getAttribute for server side only: in case you want to pass attribute from servlet to jsp

Comment: Its still same, no difference.

Comment: do you want to retrieve token param after clicking on href element ?
if it's the case it wont work because parameter has a request scope

Comment: if that's the case, what should I do?

Comment: pass it same way like you do for cand_id 
  <a href="/assignvote?cand_id=<%= div.getId() %>&token=<%= token %>" class="btn btn-primary">Vote</a>
and if token is related to connected user, use session instead

Comment: The thing is clicking at the `<a href="...">Vote</a>` link does not submit the form, it's just a new GET request. But `<input>` fields (i.e. `token`) are sent only with the form submission. You need to either add the token to the URL in the `href` attribute (easier way), or to use some JavaScript to submit the form when clicking the *Vote* link.